# import csv file in h2 database in several column

Tags: sql, excel, h2

In my CSV file there is:

```
prenom; nom; age
prenom1; nom1; age1
prenom2; nom2; age2
...
```

When I import my CSV file using this command:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('C:\Users\anonymous\Desktop\test.csv');
```

The main problem is that my database has 1 column with my CSV file..

I would like 3 columsn with `prenom`, `nom` and `age` with the data in each column.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure CVSREAD understands that your data is _semi-colon_ separated?

Comment: CSV = "comma-separated values".  Tabs are often accepted implicitly (though I don't know about whether SQL accepts them.)  If you can change the file format use commas instead and you should be OK.

Answer (score 3):

As [@jdv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1531971/jdv) stated, you must specify the field separator if it is not the default `,`. The `null` specifies that the column names will be parsed from the first row.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('C:\Users\anonymous\Desktop\test.csv',null,'fieldSeparator=;');
```

Keep in mind you may have to specify `charset=Cp1252` as well, if the CSV file was generated with Excel. If you see something like `prÃ©nom` you have the wrong encoding.